# Launch another application on windows 8.1 with a button

Tags: c#, windows, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

How to launch another application when user click a button on windows 8.1?

The `xaml`:

```
<Button x:Name=x:Name="ppBtn" Source="images/new icon/BSE-w8-portal-ikon-256px.png" Margin="20,-3,30,0" Click="ppBtn_Clicked" Height="204">
```

Comment: Store Apps are running in a sandbox, so you can't just launch any application from them. You may, however, call custom protocol (say, a call to be handled by Skype) or a file to be handled by the associated app

Comment: can you give me a example?